# Find a limit of function: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(-2)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{x} $

Tags: limits

Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{(-2)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{x} \right)$

$\lfloor x \rfloor$ - is the floor function

From graphic it seems that this limit is different from right and left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$\lfloor x \rfloor = -1$ for all $-1 < x < 0$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor = 0$ for all $0 < x < 1$.

To find the limit $x \to 0^-$, replace $\lfloor x \rfloor$ with $-1$, and then let $x \to 0^-$ ($x < 0$ and $x \to 0$)

To find the limit $x \to 0^+$, replace $\lfloor x \rfloor$ with $0$, and then let $x \to 0^+$ ($x > 0$ and $x \to 0$)

For the limit $x \to 0$ to exist, we need the limit $x \to 0^-$ and the limit $x \to 0^+$ to be equal and finite.

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{(-2)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{x} \right)$ = \infty

Comment: @NowakGrzegorz So the limit does not exist

Comment: @NowakGrzegorz \infty will give $\infty$

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\left(\frac{(-2)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{x} \right)$ = 0

Comment: @NowakGrzegorz If $-1 < x<0$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor = -1$ so

$$\frac{(-2)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{x} = - \frac{1}{2x}$$

Since $x<0$, $ - \frac{1}{2x} > 0$ and as $x \to 0^-$, $ - \frac{1}{2x} \to + \infty$

Comment: @NowakGrzegorz You need the \infty to be between the dollar signs.

Comment: I know $\infty$ but I can't edit after 5 minuts

Comment: THE ANSWER: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{(-2)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{x} \right)$ = $+ \infty$ Is it ok?

Comment: @NowakGrzegorz So we say that the limit does not exist. The limit needs to be finite for it to be said to exist. We can say that $\mathrm f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$. But we say that $\lim_{x \to 0} \mathrm f(x)$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not restrictive to assume your function is defined over $(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$, we have
$$
\lfloor x\rfloor=\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if $-1<x<0$} \\[4px]
0 & \text{if $0<x<1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(-2)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}{x}=
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty
$$
Also
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{(-2)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}{x}=
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{-1/2}{x}=+\infty
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(-2)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}{x}=+\infty
$$